# Reading a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a Service which returns JSON using C#'s `JavaScriptSerializer` class.

jQuery

```
        $.get('GlobalService/Index',
            { crudOperation: crudOperation,
                globalType: globalType,
                globalObject: globalObject
            },
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

the callback function displays in the alert

> [object XMLDocument]

How do I get to and parse the JSON object?  The object has basic construction

`{"field1":"data","field2":"more data",/*...~10 more of these*/}`

Comment: try using `console.log(data)` and see what is in the console.

Comment: you can then expand that object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.get('GlobalService/Index',
{ 
    crudOperation: crudOperation,
    globalType: globalType,
    globalObject: globalObject
},
function (data) {
    // access it as you would normally access a JS object
    alert(data.field1);
}, 
'json'); // do not forget to pass the json data type here, otherwise it 
         // will just guess it (probably wrong, as it shows in your case)
```

Comment: This changed the alert to `[object Object]`.  I expected to see the full JSON string. @Neal did a good job explaining to me why this is the case.  +1 because the information is still useful.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey: Giving a way to access the object with giving a solution to retrieve the JSON object, are two different things. It changed it to that type, because that's what a JSON object is. You can explore the object any way you like (even in `console.log()`), but without passing the `JSON` data type, you will still not be able to access it (not at least without parsing it).

Comment: Oh wait, you are right.  I need the 'json' specifier or I can't access the object with the `data.fieldX` syntax.  Giving you answer credit.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way.
 @see [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

also,

[parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine, just an alert cannot show the object data:

```
    $.get('GlobalService/Index',
        { crudOperation: crudOperation,
            globalType: globalType,
            globalObject: globalObject
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data); //view data in console
            alert(data.field1);
        });
```

Comment: The console just displays `[object XMLDocument]`, same as alert. +1 because that is a cool firebug ability that I did not know about, thanks. –

Comment: you can then expand that object (either in firebug or in chrome's console)

Comment: You are correct.  In firebug, console tab, Expand the Get request, then click the Response tab.  The JSON will be there in all its glory.  From there I can just use `data.fieldX` to get to the actual data.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a `dataType` of "**json**" in order to let the method know how parse the returned data:

```
      $.get('GlobalService/Index',
            { crudOperation: crudOperation,
                globalType: globalType,
                globalObject: globalObject
            },
            function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }, 'json');
```

See $.get() documentation at jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.

Note that if you don't specify `dataType`, jQuery will do a ***smart guess*** of what the server is returning and **it is very clear** that it is misunderstanding the server response with an XML block of code.